# How to write Output of AUGraph to an External AudioFile of WAV or AIF formats?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, midi, audiounit

In my iOS app i am playing a MIDI file using Music Player & Music Sequence. And i'm getting AUGraph here by calling "MusicSequenceGetAUGraph" method of the Music Sequence.
Now i want to save the same Output of this AUGraph to an External File. How can i do that?
Can any one help me?

Here i'm not using any Nodes to create AUGraph. I'm getting the Graph directly from Music Sequence.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my AUGraph

AudioUnitGraph 0x246104F:

Member Nodes:

```
node 1: 'aumu' 'samp' 'appl', instance 0x1c558830 O I
node 2: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x1c54a550 O I
```

Connections:

```
node   1 bus   0 => node   2 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
```

CurrentState:
    mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isRunning=T (1)

Comment: Add a render notification to your AUGraph, then write the data to a file with the ExtAudioFile API. See the code posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951458/how-to-write-output-of-augraph-to-a-file (your solution will be a little bit different since it'll be a render notification instead of an input callback, but very similar)

Answer (score 0):

There is an example [here](https://github.com/aranm/iPhone-ExtAudioFile-Record) of writing the output of an AUGraph to a file