# Callback function of output unit of audio graph - can't read data

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio

I am trying to capture the input data stream to the output unit in an audio graph so I can write it to a file. I have registered an input callback function for the output unit (default output) after creating the graph like so:

```
    AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext (NULL, &cd);
if (comp == NULL) {
    printf ("can't get output unit");
    exit (-1);
}
CheckError (AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &player->outputUnit),
            "Couldn't open component for outputUnit"); // outputUnit is of type AudioUnit

// register render callback
AURenderCallbackStruct input;
input.inputProc = MyRenderProc;
input.inputProcRefCon = player;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(player->outputUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &input,
                                sizeof(input)),
           "AudioUnitSetProperty failed");

// initialize unit
CheckError (AudioUnitInitialize(player->outputUnit),"Couldn't initialize output unit");
```

The callback function gets called but when I try to read the input data stream from ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, all I get is zeros. Here is the callback function:

```
OSStatus MyRenderProc(void *inRefCon, // PLAYER CODE
                        AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                        const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                        UInt32 inBusNumber,
                        UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                        AudioBufferList * ioData) {

int frame = 0;
Float32 leftFloat = 0;
Float32 rightFloat = 0;
NSNumber *leftNumber;
NSNumber *rightNumber;
for (frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; ++frame)
{
    Float32 *data = (Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    leftFloat = (data)[frame];
    leftNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:leftFloat];
    (data)[frame] = 0;

    // copy to right channel too
    data = (Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;
    rightFloat = (data)[frame];
    rightNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(data)[frame]];
    (data)[frame] = 0;

    [leftData addObject:leftNumber];
    [rightData addObject:rightNumber];

}

return noErr;
}
```

Furthermore, if I don't zero out the data I hear noise during playback, which tells me I am misinterpreting the function of the mBuffers. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the `leftData` and `rightData` arrays doing?  They're not declared in the code snippet up there.

Comment: You must either render data from somewhere (input in your case), or fill the buffer with something (zeroes in your case). Else, whatever was left in the buffer will keep on playing (noise in your case).

Comment: Michael - leftData and rightData are NSMutableArray objects that I am using only for quick accessibility to data to see if anything is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *capturing input data* from an `AUGraph` is the task, the critical part of code (more or less) boils down to this simplest one-channel demo example:

```
OSStatus MyRenderProc(void *inRefCon, 
                      AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                      const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                      UInt32 inBusNumber,
                      UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                      AudioBufferList * ioData) 
{        
    Float32 buf [inNumberFrames]; //just for one channel!

    MyMIDIPlayer *player = (MyMIDIPlayer *)inRefCon;

    if (*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
        static int TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError = (1 << 8);
        if (!(*ioActionFlags & TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError)){

            Float32* data = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData; //just for one channel!

            memcpy(buf, data, inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));

            //do something with buff - there are nice examples of ExtAudioFileWriteAsync()
        }
    }
    return noErr;
}
```

In the `setupAUGraph()` this callback can be set up in the following way:

```
void setupAUGraph(MyMIDIPlayer *player) 
{
    // the beginning follows the textbook example setup pattern
    {…  …  …}

    // this is the specific part
    AURenderCallbackStruct input = {0};
    input.inputProc = MyRenderProc;
    input.inputProcRefCon = player->instrumentUnit;

    CheckError(AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(player->instrumentUnit,
                                    MyRenderProc,
                                    &player),
           "AudioUnitAddRenderNotify Failed");

    // now initialize the graph (causes resources to be allocated)
    CheckError(AUGraphInitialize(player->graph),
           "AUGraphInitialize failed");
}
```

Please note that the render callback "taps" the connection between the output of instrument node and input of output node, capturing what comes from upstream. The callback just copies `ioData` into some other buffer which can be saved. AFAIK, this is the simplest way of accessing `ioData` that I know it works, without breaking the API.

Please also note there are very efficient plain-C methods for testing if this works for a specific implementation - no need for Objective-C methods inside the callback. Fiddling with some `NSArray`s, adding objects etc, inside a plain-C real-time callback introduces risk of priority issues which may later become difficult to debug. CoreAudio API is written in **plain-C** for a reason. At the heart of Obj-C runtime there's much of what can't take place on the real time thread without risking glitches (locks, memory management, etc). So, it would be safer to keep off Obj-C on a **real time thread**.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Yes, I realize the risk of using Objective-C. It's just there to get quick access to the data to see if it's working.

Comment: I have added the call to AudioUnitRender() to the callback but now I get an error: (-50) or (-10877) depending on the value that I use for the "kInputBus" parameter, as you call it. I am debugging that now.

Comment: One question I have is if I can do all of this using the default output. The book "Learning Core Audio" seems to suggest that I need to us the generic output to get access to the data, although it doesn't state it explicitly.

Comment: Here is the render call: 

CheckError(AudioUnitRender(player->outputUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 0, inNumberFrames, ioData), "AudioUnitRender failed");

Comment: That results in: Error: AudioUnitRender failed (-50)

Comment: I believe you can use default output if you don't capture data from input hardware (microphone, etc.), in which case `audioCompDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;` is needed. `kInputBus` is `1`. The user parameter error `-50` is about audio stream basic description.

Comment: I am not using the microphone. I am sending MIDI commands to DLS Synth. When I use 1 for the kInputBus parameter I get error -10877.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I've been away. My answer is now updated and extended. Hope it can help better now.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much! Doing my happy dance. I really do appreciate your time and wisdom on this, user3078414.

Comment: Glad I could share something something that could help. This is kind of "dark corner" of CoreAudio. In the aforementioned (good) textbook the necessity of `AUGraph` API is somewhat _overestimated_, but in cases where it's really needed, such as yours, it's rather _"underdocumented"_.

Comment: Since you use an AUGraph, how could it be possible to check the number of  `ioData->mNumberBuffers` accurately? I use the same way you use but with a mono file I still have 2 number of frames instead of 1.

Comment: I'm needing to do something similar to this, but I need two channels for stereo. How would I modify this code to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

A render callback on an output Audio Unit isn't for capturing the output data.  It's to provide output data (sample mBuffers) for the output unit to play.

Comment: Then there is no way to do this using the default output? If that is the case, then how about with the generic output?

Comment: In `AUGraph` API the render callbacks are used as connections between `AU` component instances. The only way that I found can work (without breaking the API) would be registering the _callback_ with "AudioUnitAddRenderNotify()" mechanism, in order to capture data from 'upstream' of output AU.