# iOS Core Audio: In which Audio Unit to implement the callback to render the necessary data?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I have a fully working audio model. There are three Audio Unit:
equalizerUnit,
mixerUnit,
remoteIOUnit. 
With AUGraph and Nodes (equalizerNode, mixerNode, remoteNode), they are correctly connected to each other: equalizerUnit ->  mixerUnit -> remoteIOUnit.

equalizerNode rendered callback: 
AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(audioGraph, equlizerNode, 0, &callbackStruct) where using the ExtAudioFileRead, the date is converted and, as a result, playback on the device. Everything works fine, all units work out correctly.

I want to add visualization. The buffer and data processing to fft is ready, the only question is where to render the callback in order to get the desired data?

Comment: This is what  `AUGraphAddRenderNotify` is for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37589489/22147 NB that the callback you install called twice, that's why the linked answer checks for `kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: The first comment should be put in an answer.